# Python Pandas from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary

```
x={'XYZ': [4, 5, 6], 'ABC': [1, 2, 3]}
```

I want a `pd.DataFrame` like this:

```
     'SomeColumnName'
'XYZ'   [4,5,6]
'ABC'   [1,2,3]
```

Whatever I do, it splits the list of x.values() in 3 separate columns. I could do a '~'.join before creating the Dataframe. Just wondering if there was an easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just input the data as:

```
x={'XYZ': [[4, 5, 6]], 'ABC': [[1, 2, 3]]}
```

Then you get:

```
In [7]: pd.DataFrame(x).transpose()
Out[7]:
             0
ABC  [1, 2, 3]
XYZ  [4, 5, 6]
```

You can recode your dictionary using:

```
for key in x.keys():
        x[key] = [x[key]]
```

Comment: AH, beautiful... that is a better way.

Comment: @PankajSingh, check out this introduction to `Pandas` [data structures](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html). I think the reason you're being downvoted (though the voters should certainly say why they're downvoting), is because the question pertains to afundamental element of `Pandas`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I did it

z = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(x.items()),columns=['A','SomeColumnName'],index='A')

Problem was - I wasnt using list() for data